# Why is cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY failing with Unsupported depth of input image?

Tags: python, opencv, grayscale

I have a mask that is generated from an ML program which is (544,544,1). RGB image is (544,544,3). I need to find the contours in the mask and draw them on RGB image. I was trying to convert the mask into grayscale but all attempts failed likely due to format issues.

> resized_image - Incomming RGB image
> mask - Mask generated from ML script

```
print(f"Resized rgb image shape : {resized_image.shape}, Mask image shape {mask.shape}")
tmp_mask = np.zeros(resized_image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)+255 
bump = tmp_mask * mask
print(bump.shape)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(bump, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

The outputs are as follows :

```
Resized rgb image shape : (544, 544, 3), Mask image shape (544, 544, 1)
(544, 544, 3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-07ef46f74c90> in <module>
     12     bump = tmp_mask * mask
     13     print(bump.shape)
---> 14     gray = cv2.cvtColor(bump, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
     15 
     16     #gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(bump, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

error: OpenCV(4.5.5) d:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:94: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0x7123906f::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0x7123906f::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 4 (CV_32S)
```

How can I fix the format issue (Unsupported depth of input image) here? Is there any other simpler way to find the contours in the mask image?

Comment: What is `bump`? If that is a one-channel image, it is not `RGB` and you can't convert it from `RGB` to `grayscale`.

Comment: bump is (544,544,3)

Comment: Why does it think it's 4 channel when it is clearly 3 channel?

Comment: it **does not** think "4 channel". it says `4`, which is OpenCV's type code for `CV_32S`. depth is the size of elements, not part of the shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reproduce

```py
cv2.cvtColor(np.ones((30,30,3), dtype=np.int32), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

### Explain

`depth` is not the channel (part of array shape), it is the number of bytes for each number. int32 will use 4*8 bits to represent an integer, and uint8 just uses 1*8 bits.

`cvtColor` needs `np.float32`, or `np.uint8` as dtype.

We can guess `tmp_mask.dtype` == `np.uint8`

So, please check the `dtype` of the `mask` variable by `print(mask.dtype)`

Comment: mask is single channel : (544, 544, 1)

Comment: mask is a single channel : (544, 544, 1). So what should be the fix ? Why is the error "'depth' is 4 (CV_32S)". Where is the 4th channel here ?

Comment: `depth` is not the channel, it is the length of bytes for each number, `int32` will use 4*8 bits to represent an integer, and `uint8` just uses 1*8 bits, please `print(mask.dtype)`

Comment: Finally got it working. The issue was mask.dtype was 64 bit. I converted back to uint8 with mask = mask.astype(np.uint8). Everything is a breeze now . . . .!

Comment: @FavorMylikes you can add your comment to the answer +1